# android: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, variables

I'm developing an android application for a month. and today when I cleaned my project (project>clean...), I got "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error and i can't run my app.

I Googled for solution and did every solution for this problem but not success.

Note: I removed all imports R and cleaned my project again but the problem exists.

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for bad English!

**Edit: problem solved. there was some errors in one of xml files.**

Comment: Do you have any other problems/errors in your project? Try to fix them, these can prevent the R file from generating. (Also, you need to import your own R, like com.myapp.example.R)

Comment: right click on the project and click buildpath

Comment: Answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error

Comment: added 'import <myAppPackage>.R' and cleaned again. and I have not other errors. all errors are about R variable!

Comment: sorry guys. problem solved. there was an error in one of xml layout files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this appears when you have errors in layout files or other xml files. Also take care that images have names that don t contain upper caracters

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem

```
LinearLayout android:id="@id/TelNoLayout"
```

replace to

```
LinearLayout android:id="@+id/TelNoLayout"
```

and build